# Applying aggregate functions to multiple properties with LINQ GroupBy

Tags: vb.net, linq, aggregate, anonymous-types

I have a list of `Object` (it's called: `sourceList`)
`Object` contains: Id, Num1, Num2, Num3, Name, Lname

Assume I have the following list:

```
1, 1, 5, 9, 'a', 'b'
1, 2, 3, 2, 'b', 'm'
2, 5, 8, 7, 'r', 'a'
```

How can I return another list (of `object2`) that returns a new list:

```
Id, sum of num1, sum of num2
```

For the example above, it should return a list of `object2` that contains:

```
1, 3, 8
2, 5, 8
```

I tried:

```
Dim a = sourceList.GroupBy(Function(item) item.Id).
        Select(Function(x) x.Sum(Function(y) y.Num1)).ToList()
```

But I don't know how to sum `num2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to combine anonymous types with initializer expressions, which is the way LINQ in fluent style does it implicitly. So e.g.

```
Dim a = sourceList.GroupBy(Function(item) item.Id).
        Select(Function(x) New With {.Id = x.Key,
                                     .Sum1 = x.Sum(Function(y) y.Num1),
                                     .Sum2 = x.Sum(Function(y) y.Num2),
                                     .Sum3 = x.Sum(Function(y) y.Num3)}).ToList()
```

Tested this and it seems to work fine. (The equivalent fluent style is

```
Dim fluent = (From item In sourceList
              Group By item.Id Into Sum1 = Sum(item.Num1),
                                    Sum2 = Sum(item.Num2),
                                    Sum3 = Sum(item.Num3)).ToList()
```

which also works great and is arguably a bit easier to read.)