# Returning indexed property from anonymous type

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, anonymous-types

My LINQ query returns totals for each month of the year, which I'm exposing as twelve properties (named January, February, March...) of the anonymous type. This makes it impossible to loop through the twelve values. Is there a way to instead return a single indexed property containing all 12 values?

This is what I have:

```
Dim MyTotals = Aggregate CostRow In AllTargetRows _
               Into January = Sum(CostRow.January), 
                    February = Sum(CostRow.February), 
                    March = Sum(CostRow.March), _
                    ...
                    Total = Sum(CostRow.Total)
```

This is what I want to achieve (compiler doesn't like this one):

```
Dim MyTotals = Aggregate CostRow In AllTargetRows _
               Into Values = {Sum(CostRow.January), 
                              Sum(CostRow.February), 
                              Sum(CostRow.March), _
                              ...
                              },
                    Total = Sum(CostRow.Total)
```

I would then be able to do `MyTotals.Values(i)` kind of stuff.

Comment: What about dictionary?

Comment: @ilanS: A `Dictionary` would do I guess. Question is, how?!

Comment: What exactly do you by "This makes it impossible to loop through the twelve values." ?

Comment: Try using `Group By` as this answer suggests:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365169/applying-aggregate-functions-to-multiple-properties-with-linq-groupby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that pops into mind for me is to use the `Aggregate` function to populate a dictionary.  Something like this:

```
Dim MyTotals =
    AllTargetRows
    .Aggregate(
        new Dictionary<string, int>()
            {
                { "January", 0 },
                { "February", 0 },
                { "March", 0 },
                { "April", 0 },
                { "May", 0 },
                { "June", 0 },
                { "July", 0 },
                { "August", 0 },
                { "September", 0 },
                { "October", 0 },
                { "November", 0 },
                { "December", 0 },
                { "Total", 0 }
            },
        (acc, costRow) => 
            {
                acc["January"] += costRow.January;
                acc["February"] += costRow.February;
                acc["March"] += costRow.March;
                acc["April"] += costRow.April;
                acc["May"] += costRow.May;
                acc["June"] += costRow.June;
                acc["July"] += costRow.July;
                acc["August"] += costRow.August;
                acc["September"] += costRow.September;
                acc["October"] += costRow.October;
                acc["November"] += costRow.November;
                acc["December"] += costRow.December;
                acc["Total"] += costRow.Total;
                return acc;
            });
```

This will result in a dictionary where the keys are the months of the year (and 'total') and the values are the sums of the values for each month.

Sorry, I missed the VB.NET tag.  VB.NET is not my strong suit but I think this is the equivalent in VB.NET.

```
Dim MyTotals = _
    AllTargetRows _
    .Aggregate( _
        New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From { _
            {"January", 0}, _
            {"February", 0}, _
            {"March", 0}, _
            {"April", 0}, _
            {"May", 0}, _
            {"June", 0}, _
            {"July", 0}, _
            {"August", 0}, _
            {"September", 0}, _
            {"October", 0}, _
            {"November", 0}, _
            {"December", 0}, _
            {"Total", 0} _
        }, _
        Function(acc, costRow) 
            acc("January") += costRow.January
            acc("February") += costRow.February
            acc("March") += costRow.March
            acc("April") += costRow.April
            acc("May") += costRow.May
            acc("June") += costRow.June
            acc("July") += costRow.July
            acc("August") += costRow.August
            acc("September") += costRow.September
            acc("October") += costRow.October
            acc("November") += costRow.November
            acc("December") += costRow.December
            acc("Total") += costRow.Total
            Return acc
        End Function)
```

I do not know if this overload of the `Aggregate` function can be converted to query syntax.  An (possibly simpler) alternative is to forego LINQ altogether and simply create the dictionary before running your query and then loop over each row and populate the dictionary that way.  Something like this:

```
Dim MyTotals = _
    New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From { _
        {"January", 0}, _
        {"February", 0}, _
        {"March", 0}, _
        {"April", 0}, _
        {"May", 0}, _
        {"June", 0}, _
        {"July", 0}, _
        {"August", 0}, _
        {"September", 0}, _
        {"October", 0}, _
        {"November", 0}, _
        {"December", 0}, _
        {"Total", 0}}

For Each costRow as AllTargetRow in AllTargetRows
    MyTotals("January") += costRow.January
    MyTotals("February") += costRow.February
    MyTotals("March") += costRow.March
    MyTotals("April") += costRow.April
    MyTotals("May") += costRow.May
    MyTotals("June") += costRow.June
    MyTotals("July") += costRow.July
    MyTotals("August") += costRow.August
    MyTotals("September") += costRow.September
    MyTotals("October") += costRow.October
    MyTotals("November") += costRow.November
    MyTotals("December") += costRow.December
    MyTotals("Total") += costRow.Total
Next
```

Comment: Is this VB.NET or C#?

Comment: Also do you know the query syntax of it?